# SonarQube not excluding a specific rule

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

We are trying to suppress a couple of specific rules: csharpsquid:S3990 & csharpsquid:S4041 from analysis, we can see that the rule csharpsquid:S4041 is being excluded but violations\issues for csharpsquid:S3990 are still being shown in analysis report.

Format given,
Rule Key Pattern : csharpsquid:S3990
File Path pattern : `**/*.*`

Csharp plugin version: 7.0.1 (build 4822)
SonarQube version: 6.7.1

We run analysis from Sonarqube VSTS tasks.

Has anyone else faced this or is it something specific about the rule that it cannot be suppressed?

Also can we enforce SonarQube to use a specific ruleset for analysis instead of default SonarQube ruleset?

Comment: Does any one know about this specific issue? We are stuck with this.

Comment: Do you want to suppress specific rules or specific issues found for a rule?